# How many ways are there to go from $A$ to $B$?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many paths are there to go from $A$ to $B$ in the following figure:
>   [image: Figure problem]

**Conditions:**

1. I'm not able to touch $C$
2. I can go up, down, left or right
3. I'm  not able to pass a line twice

I couldn't came up with any idea and I counted them. I believe there are 18.

Comment: Strategy: There are two nodes through which you must get to in order to get to $B$, so your question is synonymous with how many paths are there from $A$ to the junction below $C$ plus how many paths are there from $A$ to the junction above $B$. Then for those two points you can divide the problem again and again until each piece is small enough for you to confidently count. -- and bear in mind you have to consider only paths to the point in question that don't block the way from that point to $B$.

Comment: Is there  a way of solving the problem without counting as the previous comment ?